# don't change a property in ChangePropertycallback

Tags: wpf, listview, dependency-properties, icollectionview, itemsource

I have a `ListView` and binding `ItemSource` to a `ICollectionView` property, and binding selected item to a dp property.

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Selected",
                                  typeof(Myclass),
                                  typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(SelectedContactChange));


    static void SelectedContactChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControlcontrol = d as MyControl;
        control.MYView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((Myclass)e.NewValue).Numbers);
    }
```

and i have another list view and binding itemsource to MYView propert.

```
 ICollectionView _myView;
    public ICollectionView MYView
    {
        get { return _myView; }
        set
        {
            _myView= value;
        }
    }
```

When change the SelectedProperty i set value for MYView, but don't show new value in listview that binding with MYView!!!

How to change MYView property when changed SelectedProperty  ??

Comment: when you assign value to the binding source directly then binding breaks down

Comment: "i want to set MYView, but don't change MYView", what does that mean? Please be more precise.

Comment: you should do it like bind the selectedItem to some property in viewmodel and then do what you doing here in VM and assign value to MYView there

Comment: @Clemens :  i set value for MYView, but don't show new value in listview that binding with MYView!!!

Comment: @ethicallogics :what does that mean? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but i guess that your ListView's ItemsSource is bound to the `MYView` property of your MyControl class, perhaps like this:

```
<MyControl x:Name="myControl" ... />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MYView, ElementName=myControl}" />
```

When you now change the value of the `MYView` property, there is no mechanism that notifies the binding of the change. You should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx) and raise the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event when `MYView` changes:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICollectionView MYView
    {
        get { return _myView; }
        set
        {
            _myView = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MYView"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could define `MYView` as another dependency property.

Comment: Thanks, I have a custom control and use RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} for listview ... i use PropertyChanged but don't show new item.

Comment: The problem is the same, the binding has to be notified. Think about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I use a dependency property for MYView .